# How to condition on if a browser is included in a browserslist using Gulp?

Tags: gulp, browser-detection

Is it possible to check if a particular browser is included in your browserslist using Gulp? I would like to include [this script](https://philipwalton.com/articles/deploying-es2015-code-in-production-today/) if and only if “Safari 10” is included in the browserslist.

I know that [browserl.ist](http://browserl.ist) displays the browsers included in a particular browserslist, but ideally I would like to do it programmatically so that I can condition things on it in my gulpfile.js. This, after all, must be what all plugins that use browserslist do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `npm install --save-dev browserslist fs` and then write a gulpfile.js like this

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      browserslist = require('browserslist'),
      fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('test', () => {
  const browsers = browserslist(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json')).browserslist);

  if (browsers.filter(browser => browser.includes('safari 10.1')).length) {
    // Do something if Safari 10.1 is included in browserslist
  } else {
    // Do something else if it isn't
  }

  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `npx browserslist` to list all the browsers included in your browserslist query.

Gulp is not needed to run that command but if you wanted to, you could create a Gulp task to run it in your terminal.

Comment: That was nice, but then I don't know how to capture the output from `npx browserslist` in order to use it in Gulp.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Did you get it working with a gulp task?